# How to handle IP addresses when linking docker containers with each other using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, ip, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to build a complete development stack.

The application needs a mysql server to work.

The mysql server is an external container setup by docker-compose:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
        - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./docker/mysql.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

The application has its own docker-compose.yml and references the mysql container:

```
my-application:
    build: . # the Dockerfile resides in the current folder
    ports:
        - "9180:80"
        - "9543:443"
    external_links:
        - mysql_mysql_1:mysql
environment:
    DOCKER_ENVIRONMENT: dev
    DB_NAME: local_db
    DB_PASS: password
    DB_USER: root
    DB_HOST: # how to set the mysql's IP address?
```

I cannot pass them in the docker-compose as it is dynamic.

I know that the application is aware of the mysql IP address, as I have certain variables set:

```
application-container$ env|grep ADDR 
    MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.241
```

Yet this is not my required `DB_HOST`.

Can I map the variable somehow to `DB_HOST` or set it differently?

Comment: Why your mysql server is on an external docker-composer.yml file? Is this really required?
Usually, if you have containerized applications that needs to run together you have to configure the in only one docker-composer.yml.

Comment: @nessuno I want to use that mysql container for multiple projects. I don't need 12 mysql servers flying around. Furthermore, I map the mysql data to my a large HDD located at `/data/mysql`, as the mysql databse can become quite massive. If you have multiple mysql instances mapped to the same folder would lead to fileysystem lock issues.

Comment: You can put the mysql container configuration together with your application, you just only have to run docker-compose with the `--no-recreate` flag, I guess.
After that you have only one mysql container up, and you can reference that container directly in the docker-compose.yml file using his name. Thus make `DB_HOST: mysql`.

Comment: @nessuno Yet when I have another project also needing a mysql container than I would have two mysql containers if both were started. And if both were mapped to the same direcotory, they would lock each other out. I just want one mysql container for all applications I might develop on my machine.

Comment: Sidenote: I don't consider my initial goal to have an external db container as a good solution anymore. Rather, each application stack should work on its own.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't have to set the IP, but you can reference the container's virtual *hostname*, and this is the same value as you named your linked container.

This means you can indeed set the DB_HOST from within the `docker-compose.yml`, either with `links` (recommended) or `external_links`:

```
your_application:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "9180:80"
        - "9543:443"
    external_links:
        - mysql_mysql_1:docker-mysql
    environment:
        DB_HOST: docker-mysql
```

As when you connect to your docker container, you could connect to your mysql container:

```
application-container $ mysql -h docker-mysql -uroot -ppassword -p 3360
```

It works the same when you link container's from the same docker-composer.yml as well.

This is also [documented](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service
>   name and the link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name
>   (which will also be used for the alias).
>
> ```
> links:
>  - db
>  - db:database
>  - redis
> ```
>
> An entry with the alias' name will be created in /etc/hosts inside
>   containers for this service, e.g:
>
> ```
> 172.17.2.186  db
> 172.17.2.186  database
> 172.17.2.187  redis
> ```
>
> Environment variables will also be created - see the [environment
>   variable reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env/) for details.

Comment: Be careful, As of today with the version 2 of the docker-compose file, the environment variable reference are not created anymore. see https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

Comment: @MartinGOYOT That's true. In version 2, the containers should be able to connect to each other out of the box though due the changed networking. I'll check if I can add a version 2 example. If you are in the middle of creating it just now, you may too post a new answer for version 2.

Comment: well your answer works well on version 2. I was only saying this in regards of the
 "Environment variables will also be created - see the environment variable reference for details."

Comment: THANK YOU! I kept trying to connect either to 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' but I never ever had the idea to use the container name which can be found in `docker-compose ps`.