# Can't start application within docker using linked mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm using docker to run my nodejs app with few databases, and one of them is mysql.

I found mysql image on the docker hub and use it in my **docker-compose.yml**

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/app/
  working_dir: /var/www/app/
  command: node app.js
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - mongo
    - elasticsearch
    - mysql

mysql:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: testdb

mongo:
  image: mongo

elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
```

Everything builds and application uses mysql conenction config that seems like this:

```
mysql: {
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'testdb'
    }
```

Application trying to start and stops on the the mysql connection error.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

I'm wondering if docker mysql image could be linked to the app container via compose file. Please explain how to link mysql container properly.

Thanks in advance!

**My own answer**

When you're using any type of linking other containers(external_link or link) you may set in your application config file the process environment variables according to the name of the container

```
process.env.<container_name>_PORT_<container_port>
```

**SailsJS to Mongo Example:**

I have a container with name `mongo_dev` which is connected in my docker compose file as

```
external_links:
  - mongo_dev
```

so in my application config this environment variable used like this:

```
mongo: {
      module   : 'sails-mongo',
      host     : process.env.MONGO_DEV_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost',
      port     : process.env.MONGO_DEV_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT || '27017',
      user     : null,
      password : null,
      database : 'database_name'
    }
```

Comment: include the source code to mysql connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle IP addresses when linking docker containers with each other using docker-compose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021084/how-to-handle-ip-addresses-when-linking-docker-containers-with-each-other-using)

Comment: mysql connection working fine when i'm using local mysql server without docker. my connection config is already attached to this question.

Answer (score 6):

The linked `mysql` container will be your mysql host

```
mysql: { host: 'mysql', user: 'root', password: '', database: 'testdb' }
```

You will see all you linked hosts are named in `/etc/hosts` like:

```
172.17.0.2  composetest_mysql_1 fffb39e63df6
172.17.0.2  mysql fffb39e63df6 composetest_mysql_1
172.17.0.2  mysql_1 fffb39e63df6 composetest_mysql_1
```

Comment: The `/etc/hosts` bit was quite helpful to me for debugging

Comment: Docker has  moved away from links to a local DNS server on user defined networks so this won't be available for non linked containers

Answer (score 0):

Use Connection String as Follows:
`mysql://username:password@mysql:3306/demo`