# PHP CLI script & MySQL with Docker compose

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

My goal is that running a PHP script with Docker compose.

I somehow found how to execute a PHP example script using Dockerfile like the following.

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  test.php

$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM php:7.0-cli
COPY ./test.php /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
CMD [ "php", "./test.php" ]

$ cat test.php 
<?php
phpinfo();

$ docker build -t my-php-app .

$ docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app my-php-app
```

https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/

I'm looking into how to connect into MySQL from the PHP script.

Any help will be helpful for me.

---

Update 1

I had little progress. I was able to connect to the container of mysql from PHP container.

```
$ cat index.php 
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("database", "admin", "12dlql*41");
echo $mysqli->server_info;

$ docker run -d --name database -e MYSQL_USER=admin -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=12dlql*41 -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql:latest

$ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app --link database tommylau/php php index.php
5.7.21
```

https://www.shiphp.com/blog/2017/php-mysql-docker

---

Update 2

Thanks to everyone I was able to find the way.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.1.9-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev \
  && pecl install memcached-3.0.3 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable memcached opcache
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp_memcached:
    image: memcached:latest
    container_name: memcached
  myapp_mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - ./docker/:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./docker/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=counterparty
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12dlql*41
  myapp_php:
    build: .
    container_name: myapp
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    external_links:
      - database
      - memcached
```

Comment: This could maybe help you although it's postgres: https://lvthillo.com/create-simple-php-app-using-postgresql-in-docker-compose/

Comment: @lvthillo Thank you. I'll try it. It's must be useful to know docker.

Comment: Where is your `docker-comppose.yml`?

Comment: You need to link a mysql container with your php container. Using docker-compose the linked containers can reach each other through their service name. See my question / answer here, at this seems somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021084/how-to-handle-ip-addresses-when-linking-docker-containers-with-each-other-using

Comment: @k0pernikus Thank you for your comment. I'll check it and try to use docker-compse.yml

Comment: Try understanding docker first and then move forward with docker-compose. Bear in mind that docker-compose is built upon docker. If you don't understand docker, containers and linking of multiple containers, then  docker-compose won't make much sense. Your question hence seems a bit too broad in that expect. Try asking questions that focus either on your specific docker problem. Right now, too much is muddled together here.

Comment: docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/
docker-compose docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a `docker-compose.yml` file, which would interconnect your containers into one network.

For example:

```
version: '3.4'

myapp_php:
  build: ./Dockerfile
  container_name: myapp_php
myapp_mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: myapp_mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somerandompassword
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
    - MYSQL_USER=admin
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12dlql*41
```

Now when you run `docker-compose up -d`, the stack should be up with mysql having pre-set a database with your credentials.