# How to connect to cockroachdb container from other container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, cockroachdb

I've tried to mimic [MySQL way][1] to do this, but didn't work for me.
I've also tried several variation ranging from: adding network interface to
explicitly specifying container IP, none of them work (since container IP
always changed).

The error message is:

```
"could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket \"/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432\"
}
```

These are my code:

My flask app:

```py
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    database=os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
    user=os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
    password=os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
    sslmode=os.environ.get("DB_SSL"),
    host=os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
    port=os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
)
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    flask-api:
        image: flask-api:0.7.0
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        environment:
            - DB_NAME = knotdb
            - DB_HOST = roach1
            - DB_PORT = 26257
            - DB_USER = root
            - DB_SSL = disable
        links:
            - roach1
    roach1:
        image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v1.1.3
        command: start --insecure --host=127.0.0.1
        ports:
          - "26257:26257"
        volumes:
          - ./cockroach-data/roach1:/cockroach/cockroach-data
```

My other various attempts:

```
# adding network to both service : didn't work

# using ip instead of alias: didn't work
links:
  - roach1:127.0.0.1
```

1: [How to handle IP addresses when linking docker containers with each other using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021084/how-to-handle-ip-addresses-when-linking-docker-containers-with-each-other-using)

Comment: Something in your code isn't finding the database configuration you're showing; it's trying to connect to a local socket.  You should remove `links:` entirely (`roach1` will still be usable as a hostname) and also the `--host=127.0.0.1` option (it will make the database inaccessible from outside its container, though that's not the error message you show).

Comment: I might try removing the spaces in the `environment:` block: `DB_HOST=roach1` with no whitespace at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze I removed `--host=127.0.0.1`, it didn't work. But after removing space in `DB_HOST=roach1`, all worked well. Would you like to move your comment as an answer?