# I cannot connect the mysql container from server container using the docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying to connect golang container with the mysql container for nearly 5 days and every time I face the Issue about the "connection refused" problem, So I have added the Wait so that golang container wait for connection  when the Mysql container is preparing itself...but adding that Wait command in docker file and docker compose file doesn't resolve anything.

**This is the Error I have been facing**

```
 docker-compose up
Creating network "bucket-api_fullstack" with driver "br
Creating bucket-database ... done
Creating bucket-api      ... done
Attaching to bucket-database, bucket-api
bucket-api      | -------------------------------------
bucket-api      |  docker-compose-wait 2.7.2
bucket-api      | ---------------------------
bucket-api      | Starting with configuration:
bucket-api      |  - Hosts to be waiting for: [bucket-m
bucket-api      |  - Timeout before failure: 300 second
bucket-api      |  - TCP connection timeout before retr
bucket-api      |  - Sleeping time before checking for 
bucket-api      |  - Sleeping time once all hosts are a
bucket-api      |  - Sleeping time between retries: 30 
bucket-api      | -------------------------------------
bucket-api      | Checking availability of bucket-mysql
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-database | 2021-02-13 06:01:44+00:00 [Note] [Ent MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13 06:01:44+00:00 [Note] [Entd user 'mysql'
bucket-database | 2021-02-13 06:01:44+00:00 [Note] [Ent MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:45.306754Z 0 [Systemn/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.23) starting as process 1
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:45.415685Z 1 [Systemnitialization has started.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:47.738724Z 1 [Systemnitialization has ended.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.172811Z 0 [System ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060,.sock
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.350857Z 0 [System XA crash recovery...
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.357430Z 0 [System recovery finished.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.743684Z 0 [Warninificate ca.pem is self signed.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.744238Z 0 [System
mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connect channel.
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:48.918000Z 0 [Warnine configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqo all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory
bucket-database | 2021-02-13T06:01:49.233036Z 0 [Systemn/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23'  socck'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Timeout! After 300 seconds some hosts
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Timeout! After 300 seconds some hosts
bucket-api exited with code 1
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
bucket-api      | Timeout! After 300 seconds some hosts
bucket-api exited with code 1
bucket-api      | Host bucket-mysql:3305 not yet availa
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
  #Builder image build the go binary : Setting the alias as builder
FROM golang:1.15-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir /app

# add this file directory to the image
ADD . /app
# directory where the source file execution takes place
WORKDIR /app

# RUN some go commands
RUN go clean --modcache
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main ./src/

# Our production image used to run our app
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
RUN apk add --no-cache git make musl-dev go
COPY --from=builder /app/main .

# Add docker-compose-wait tool -------------------
ENV WAIT_VERSION 2.7.2
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/$WAIT_VERSION/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait


# Configure GO
ENV GOROOT /usr/lib/go
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH /go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src ${GOPATH}/bin
EXPOSE 8084
CMD ["./main"]
```

This is my dockcer-compose file

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  # MYSQL DATABASE DOCKER
  bucket-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: bucket-database
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports: 
      - "3305:3306"
    expose: 
      - "3305"
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123"
      MYSQL_USER: "bu"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "rb_db"
    networks: 
      - fullstack
    volumes: 
      - database_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    cap_add: 
      - SYS_NICE
    healthcheck: 
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "echo 'select 1' |mysql -u root -p'pagal!123' --silent"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 6
  
  #API DOCKER 
  bucket:
    image: bucketapi
    build: . 
    container_name: bucket-api
    command: sh -c "/wait"
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: bucket-mysql:3305
      WAIT_HOSTS_TIMEOUT: 300
      WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL: 30
      WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 30
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pagal!123"
      MYSQL_USER: "bu"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "123"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "rb_db"
      # MYSQL_HOST: "bucket-database"
      # MYSQL_PORT: "3305"
    ports: 
      - "8084:8084"
    restart: on-failure
    # volumes: 
    #   - ./src:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on: 
      - bucket-mysql
    networks: 
      - fullstack


volumes: 
    database_mysql:
  
networks: 
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my Go MySQL connection code

```
func init() {
    // loaDerr := godotenv.Load()
    // if loaDerr != nil {
    //  log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    // }

    username := os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER")
    password := os.Getenv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD")
    host := os.Getenv("WAIT_HOSTS")
    port := os.Getenv("MYSQL_PORT")
    schema := os.Getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE")

    fmt.Println(username, password, host, port, schema)

    dataSourceName := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        username,
        password,
        host,
       // port,
        schema,
    )

    var err error
    //connect to the database server
    client, err = sql.Open("mysql", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //checking the connection
    if connectionErr := client.Ping(); connectionErr != nil {
        panic(connectionErr.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("Database connection is been established succesfully")
}
```

please help me in this i have tried all the combinations but its not working, If I connect the mysql workbench with the running mysql container it connect normally and don't give any error but doing connection with docker and golang it giving me an error thankuu

Comment: You have several paragraphs of ALL CAPS.  On the internat, that is considered yelling.

Comment: now, its okay??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a connection between containers, Docker uses the "normal" port the service listens on.  If you're connecting to a MySQL or MariaDB container, it *always* uses port 3306; `ports:` aren't required for this case, and if they are, they're ignored.

```yaml
services:
  bucket-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    # neither expose: nor ports: are required
  bucket:
    build: .
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: bucket-mysql:3306 # ignores ports: remapping
      MYSQL_HOST: bucket-mysql
      # MYSQL_PORT: "3306"          # this is the default port
```

(`expose:` does almost nothing in modern Docker and it's safe to delete that; if you did have it, the port number there is the port number inside the container, and the `mysql` image already has `EXPOSE 3306` in its Dockerfile.  You can also safely rely on Compose's default values for `networks:`, `container_name:`, and the built `image:` name, plus you shouldn't usually need to override `command:` from what your Dockerfile specifies for its `CMD`.  This might help simplify your `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: I have tried to set the HOST as bucket-mysql with PORT 3306 its working but after sometime golang container get exited with code 0, how can, I resolve this ?, Thank you for helping me

Comment: David, Iam using the port 3305 because I want to connect it to the mysql workbench to check the databases

Comment: "Exited with code 0" usually means your program ran to its end, successfully; that's probably not a configuration problem.  You can set `ports: ['3305:3306']` to make the database accessible on port 3305 from outside of Docker, but even if you set this you need to use the standard port 3306 connecting between containers within Docker.

Answer (score 1):

In your DSN, you didn't set the port, which was changed from default 3306 -> 3305 in your `docker-compose`

```
 fmt.Println(username, password, host, port, schema)

    dataSourceName := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        username,
        password,
        host,
        schema,
    )
```

Add port to DSN

```
 fmt.Println(username, password, host, port, schema)

    dataSourceName := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        username,
        password,
        host,
        port
        schema,
    )
```

Comment: Good answer, I think OP might be also missing links/external-links section between containers to be able to use service alias (unless something changed in compose and those are created automatically if both containers put in same network.

Comment: Lucas, I have added the Port also but that thing is also not working, I have applied all the combinations like exposing the 3305 port, or changing some values in enviromental values, adding the wait option, and tried write all new docker file...I have done all these and these are not helping me

Comment: Regarding the links/external links ref here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021084/how-to-handle-ip-addresses-when-linking-docker-containers-with-each-other-using

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your setting:

WAIT_HOSTS: bucket-mysql:3305

You are using the same in your GO app and it should be 3306!

3305 is the port it is running on your host machine